# Retrieving untagged objects with django-tagging

Tags: django, django-tagging

What I'm looking for is a QuerySet containing any objects not tagged.

The solution I've come up with so far looks overly complicated to me:

```
# Get all tags for model
tags = Location.tags.all().order_by('name')

# Get a list of tagged location id's
tag_list = tags.values_list('name', flat=True)
tag_names = ', '.join(tag_list)
tagged_locations = Location.tagged.with_any(tag_names) \
                                  .values_list('id', flat=True)

untagged_locations = []
for location in Location.objects.all():
    if location.id not in tagged_locations:
        untagged_locations.append(location)
```

Any ideas for improvement? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is some good information in this post, so I don't feel that it should be deleted, but there is a much, much simpler solution**

I took a quick peek at the source code for django-tagging.  It looks like they use the ContentType framework and generic relations to pull it off.

Because of this, you should be able to create a [generic reverse relation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/) on your Location class to get easy access to the TaggedItem objects for a given location, if you haven't already done so:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from tagging.models import TaggedItem

class Location(models.Model):
    ...

    tagged_items = generic.GenericRelation(TaggedItem,
                                          object_id_field="object_id",
                                          content_type_field="content_type")

    ...
```

**Clarification**

My original answer suggested to do this:

```
untagged_locs = Location.objects.filter(tagged_items__isnull=True)
```

Although this would work for a 'normal join', this actually doesn't work here because the content type framework throws an additional check on `content_type_id` into the SQL for `isnull`:

```
SELECT [snip] FROM `sotest_location` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tagging_taggeditem` 
 ON (`sotest_location`.`id` = `tagging_taggeditem`.`object_id`) 
WHERE (`tagging_taggeditem`.`id` IS NULL 
 AND `tagging_taggeditem`.`content_type_id` = 4 )
```

You can hack-around it by reversing it like this:

```
untagged_locs = Location.objects.exclude(tagged_items__isnull=False)
```

But that doesn't quite feel right.

I also proposed this, but it was pointed out that [annotations don't work as expected](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10461) with the content types framework.

```
from django.db.models import Count
untagged_locs = Location.objects.annotate(
    num_tags=Count('tagged_items')).filter(num_tags=0)
```

The above code works for me in my limited test case, but it could be buggy if you have other 'taggable' objects in your model.  The reason being that it doesn't check the `content_type_id` as outlined in [the ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10461).  It generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT [snip], COUNT(`tagging_taggeditem`.`id`) AS `num_tags` 
 FROM `sotest_location` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tagging_taggeditem` 
 ON (`sotest_location`.`id` = `tagging_taggeditem`.`object_id`) 
GROUP BY `sotest_location`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`tagging_taggeditem`.`id`) = 0  
ORDER BY NULL
```

If `Location` is your only taggable object, then the above would work.

**Proposed Workaround**

Short of getting the annotation mechanism to work, here's what I would do in the meantime:

```
untagged_locs_e = Location.objects.extra(
        where=["""NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tagging_taggeditem ti
 INNER JOIN django_content_type ct ON ti.content_type_id = ct.id
 WHERE ct.model = 'location'
  AND ti.object_id = myapp_location.id)"""]
)
```

This adds an additional WHERE clause to the SQL:

```
SELECT [snip] FROM `myapp_location` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tagging_taggeditem ti
 INNER JOIN django_content_type ct ON ti.content_type_id = ct.id
  WHERE ct.model = 'location'
   AND ti.object_id = myapp_location.id)
```

It joins to the `django_content_type` table to ensure that you're looking at the appropriate 
 content type for your model in the case where you have more than one taggable model type.

Change `myapp_location.id` to match your table name.  There's probably a way to avoid hard-coding the table names, but you can figure that out if it's important to you.

Adjust accordingly if you're not using MySQL.

Comment: The 'object\_id\_field' and 'content\_type\_field' parameters are gratuitous here since they default exactly to what is being passed, but I felt including them would be helpful to show the API.

Comment: Thanks for providing a great answer! However, I might be doing something wrong but I can't get it to work. I can get `Location.objects.filter(tagged_items__isnull=False)` to give me the set of tagged items but `Location.objects.filter(tagged_items__isnull=True)` just gives me an empty query set.

Comment: Also, do annotations really work correctly with generic relations? The following ticket indicates it does not: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10461

Comment: @lemonad That's unfortunate that annotations do not yet work with generic relations.  On the first comment, what if do this: `Location.objects.exclude(tagged_items__isnull=False)`  ... It seems the other way should work as I've done that before.  Tomorrow I'll put together a test case of my own and play with it.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! The reason I'm using django-tagging is because I've got several models requiring tagging so I can't rely on annotations as it stands today.

I'll try your sql suggestion later today! I can't hardcode (due to having migrations to worry about) but that should be no problem.

Comment: The reason I had so many problems was that 0.3 contained a bug and I was using in it in a way that triggered that bug. I'll accept this answer! Thanks a lot for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[location for location in Location.objects.all() if location.tags.count() == 0]
```

Comment: use parenthesis instead square brackets to get a generator instead of a list.  (mostly) same usage, far lower memory requirements.

Comment: Well, this is a list of objects not tagged, but it's not a **queryset** of objects not tagged.  Key differences being that it has no manager functionality and it isn't lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Location` class uses the `tagging.fields.TagField` utility.

```
from tagging.fields import TagField
class Location(models.Model):
    tags = TagField()
```

You can just do this:

```
Location.objects.filter(tags='')
```

Comment: Unfortunately django-tagging does not introduce the 'tags' column so that it can be used in filters. Not for me, anyhow... and I think I've set everything up according to the "manual".

Comment: I found this by working through a simple django-tagging example on my own, but I'm thinking you have to use the `TagField` utility for it to be included on your model.

Comment: Aha, I can see how that would work. I have the `TagField` but unfortunately you can't name it `tags` if you register the model with tagging. I encountered some really ugly bugs when I did (tags were being removed when retrieving them with TaggedItem, etc.). After changing the name, everything worked fine.

I found the renaming advice here: http://tylerlesmann.com/2009/mar/06/adding-tagging-django-10-applications-existing-dat/

Comment: Oh, and the `TagField` is always empty (for me) when named something else than `tags`. It's usable in forms and the admin though.

Comment: In my test I didn't register the model so you're probably right. When you changed the name of the TagField, did you also change the name of the underlying database column? I can see how that would cause some strange behavior.